# Is parallel code supposed to run slower than sequential code, after a certain dataset size?

Tags: c#, async-await, parallel-processing, task, task-parallel-library

I'm fairly new to C# and programming in general and I was trying out parallel programming.

I have written this example code that computes the sum of an array first, using multiple threads, and then, using one thread (the main thread).

I've timed both cases.

```
static long Sum(int[] numbers, int start, int end)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        sum += numbers[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

static async Task Main()
{
    // Arrange data.
    const int COUNT = 100_000_000;
    int[] numbers = new int[COUNT];
    Random random = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = random.Next(100);
    }

    // Split task into multiple parts.
    int threadCount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    int taskCount = threadCount - 1;
    int taskSize = numbers.Length / taskCount;

    var start = DateTime.Now;

    // Run individual parts in separate threads.
    List<Task<long>> tasks = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
    {
        int begin = i * taskSize;
        int end = (i == taskCount - 1) ? numbers.Length : (i + 1) * taskSize;
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Sum(numbers, begin, end)));
    }

    // Wait for all threads to finish, as we need the result.
    var partialSums = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    long sumAsync = partialSums.Sum();

    var durationAsync = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Async sum: {sumAsync}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Async duration: {durationAsync} miliseconds");


    // Sequential
    start = DateTime.Now;

    long sumSync = Sum(numbers, 0, numbers.Length);

    var durationSync = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Sync sum: {sumSync}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Sync duration: {durationSync} miliseconds");

    var factor = durationSync / durationAsync;
    Console.WriteLine($"Factor: {factor:0.00}x");   
}
```

When the array size is 100 million, the parallel sum is computed 2x faster. (on average).
But when the array size is 1 billion, it's significantly slower than the sequential sum.

Why is it running slower?

**Hardware Information**

`Environment.ProcessorCount` = `4`

`GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes` = `8468377600`

**Timing:**

When array size is 100,000,000
[image]

When array size is 1,000,000,000
[image]

**New Test:**

This time instead of separate threads (it was 3 in my case) working on different parts of a single array of 1,000,000,000 integers, I physically divided the dataset into 3 separate arrays of 333,333,333 (one-third in size). This time, although, I'm working on adding up a billion integers on the same machine, my parallel code runs faster (as expected)

```
private static void InitArray(int[] numbers) 
{
    Random random = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = (int)random.Next(100);
    }    
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new();

    const int SIZE = 333_333_333;   // one third of a billion
    List<int[]> listOfArrays = new();
    for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount - 1; i++)
    {
        int[] numbers = new int[SIZE];
        InitArray(numbers);
        listOfArrays.Add(numbers);
    }

    // Sequential.
    stopwatch.Start();
    long syncSum = 0;
    foreach (var array in listOfArrays)
    {
        syncSum += Sum(array);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    var sequentialDuration = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Sequential sum: {syncSum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Sequential duration: {sequentialDuration} ms");


    // Parallel.
    stopwatch.Restart();
    List<Task<long>> tasks = new();
    foreach (var array in listOfArrays)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Sum(array)));
    }
    var partialSums = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    long parallelSum = partialSums.Sum();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    var parallelDuration = stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel sum: {parallelSum}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Parallel duration: {parallelDuration} ms");

    Console.WriteLine($"Factor: {sequentialDuration / parallelDuration:0.00}x");
}
```

**Timing**

[image]

I don't know if it helps figure out what went wrong in the first approach.

Comment: Probably as a result of [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing)

Comment: Also see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/october/net-matters-false-sharing):  `A simple example fitting this pattern is computing the sum of integers in an array in parallel. Each thread processes a section of the array, adding up the elements in that section into an accumulator. If the accumulators from different threads are located on the same cache line, performance is likely going to suffer as threads spend much of their time stomping over each other's cache, in effect serializing the execution of the application at the cache level.`

Comment: The more the operation is long/deals with memory, the more the system will spend computing time to synchronize, wait, etc. Si if the operation is long but simple, as maths on integers but large arrays, maybe the benefits of async is less than the efforts for maintaining tasks, context etc

Comment: But have a look at the Parallel library, which can perform nice on good computers

Comment: What is the value of `Environment.ProcessorCount` in the machine where these measurements were performed? Also what is the size of the RAM in this machine? (`GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes`)

Comment: @MatthewWatson I would have thought a larger array would be less likely to have separate blocks on the same cache line though.

Comment: @Charlieface It's not the array blocks, its the storage location of the sums that are continuously being updated that causes the issue.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The code for tha partial summing uses `long sum = 0;` which is a local variable, this would be on the stack of each thread, which is not likely to be on the same cache liine as another thread,

Comment: @Charlieface Hmm, true. I still think some kind of cache collision is happening though, but with multithreading on modern processors it's kind of hard to predict the behaviour!

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree with Charlieface. It's unlikely that the problem here is false sharing. Probably something else is going on.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I just ran it in BenchmarkDotNet and I got Async 7.953 s and Sync 8.278 s. The only change I made was `int taskCount = threadCount;` and `int end = (i + 1) * taskSize - 1;`. Even so, I would have expected it to be significantly faster even on my 4 core non-hyper-thread CPU

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I just ran it in BenchmarkDotNet and I got Async 211.4 ms and Sync 583.0 ms so it is much quicker. The only change I made was `int taskCount = threadCount;` and `int end = (i + 1) * taskSize - 1;`, and factoring out creating the `numbers` array into a `[GlobalSetup]` method

Comment: @Charlieface have you measured with both `COUNT = 100_000_000` and `COUNT = 1_000_000_000`? What's the size of the RAM in your machine?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ```Environment.ProcessorCount = 4```, ```GC.GetGCMemoryInfo().TotalAvailableMemoryBytes = 8468377600```

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I get Async 20.94 ms and Sync 59.43 ms so even more of a speedup. OP does have a point about the speedup factor of Async on smaller arrays is more than larger arrays, why is unclear. 16GB ram and and an old i5-7500 3.4Ghz.

Answer (score 4):

The asynchronous pattern is not the same as running code in parallel. The main reason for asynchronous code is better resource utilization while the computer is waiting for some kind of IO device. Your code would be better described as parallel computing or concurrent computing.

While your example should work fine, it may not be the easiest, nor optimal way to do it. The easiest option would probably be to use Parallel Linq: `numbers.AsParallel().Sum();`. There is also a [Parallel.For](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for?view=net-6.0#system-threading-tasks-parallel-for-1(system-int64-system-int64-system-threading-tasks-paralleloptions-system-func((-0))-system-func((system-int64-system-threading-tasks-parallelloopstate-0-0))-system-action((-0)))) method that should be better suited, including an overload that maintains a thread local state. Note that while the `parallel.For` will attempt to optimize its partitioning, you probably want to process chunks of data in each iteration to reduce overhead. I would try around 1-10k values or so.

We can only guess the reason your parallel method is slower. Summing numbers is a really fast operation, so it may be that the computation is limited by memory bandwith or Cache usage. And while you want your work partitions to be fairly large, using too large partitions may result in less overall parallelism if a thread gets suspended for any reason. You may also want partitions on certain sizes to work well with the caching system, see [cache associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_placement_policies#Set-associative_cache). It is also possible you are including things you did not intend to measure, like compilation times or GCs, See [benchmark .Net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) that takes care of many of the edge cases when measuring performance.

Also, *never* use DateTime for measuring performance, [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-6.0) is both much easier to use and much more accurate.

Comment: *"never use `DateTime` for measuring performance,"* -- Upvoted for this advice alone. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My machine has 4GB RAM, so initializing an `int[1_000_000_000]` results in [memory paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging). Going from `int[100_000_000]` to `int[1_000_000_000]` results in non-linear performance degradation (100x instead of 10x). Essentially a CPU-bound operation becomes I/O-bound. Instead of adding numbers, the program spends most of its time reading segments of the array from the disk. In these conditions using multiple threads can be detrimental for the overall performance, because the pattern of accessing the storage device becomes more erratic and less streamlined.

Maybe something similar happens on your 8GB RAM machine too, but I can't say for sure.